# Updating records from a List in the database using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List<Office>` , where the model `Office` consist of the following:

```
int Id
string Name
int doorNumber
int officeType
int areaCode
```

I need to update the records of the `List<Office>` where all the `areaCode` elements of this object will be updated to the value `10`.

```
        List<Office> OfficeList =   db.Offices.Where(x => x.officeType == 1).ToListAsync();

        listOfRecords = listOfRecords.Select(x => new Office
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Name = x.Name,
            doorNumber= x.doorNumber,
            officeType=x.officeType,
            areaCode = 10,
        }).ToList();

        db.Offices.UpdateRange(listOfRecords);
            await db.SaveChanges();
```

The error I get is

> Message = "The instance of entity type 'Office' cannot be tracked
>   because another instance  with the same key value for {'Id'} is
>   already being tracked. When attaching existing entities,  ensure that
>   only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

Comment: Don't create Office objects with new. Use existing one. Select(x => new Office

Comment: Try using `await db.SaveChangesAsync()` and `db.Offices.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.officeType == 1).ToListAsync()`. The list generation of `OfficeList` starts tracking on `Office` instance, which only used to read.

Comment: try this => `OfficeList.ForEach(x => x.areaCode = 10);

            db.Offices.UpdateRange(OfficeList);`

Comment: The error says what the problem is. You have several Office object with the same id. One from original collection. Another one you create in select query.

Comment: Is that *really* your code? You don't await async functions, but then await non-async functions... how did you get far enough to get a *runtime* error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just update the list and save the changes:

```
List<Office> OfficeList = db.Offices.Where(x => x.officeType == 1).ToList();

OfficeList.ForEach(office => office.areaCode = 10);

db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Still missing this important line: `db.Offices.UpdateRange(OfficeList);`.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto What would that do, that this code does not?